# Issue with page_info and products.json

Tags: api, symfony, shopify, private

I'm a developer working on a private app to manage the database and the inventory of a Shopify Online Store with Symfony and I'm looking for getting all products or inventory of the store.

I tried with the url https://{{api_key}}:{{password}}@{{shopify_domain}}/admin/products.json , but it gets only 50 to 250 products and there's more than 200 000 products on this online Store. I also tried with /admin/inventory_items, but it returns missing or invalid parameter.

Recently, I checked the documentation of cursor-based pagination and I saw that there's a parameter call page_info but I didn't know how to get it. So after many researches, I learned that I had to find the parameter on the last product displayed to go to the next product which will be on the next page. I also seen that there was a parameter on GraphQL which is called storefrontId, it looked like page_info so I tried to add it to the URL but it didn't worked. I noticed that there were a = to the end of the URL, so I tried it with =0 =1 =2 and =3, also with =rel=next =next and =page=2 but it returns the same error : { "errors": { "page_info": "Invalid value." } }

For people who will find me a solution with downloading data and uploading it daily, this is not relevant because on this online store there is more than 200 000 products and the employee aren't developer.
If there is a possibility to update and display the database in real-time, without uploading a file, it would be perfect !

If you know how to help me, I'm open to suggestions !

Thanks,
Karim HADJ-ABDELKADER

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `page_info` should be unique ID and not just number, look at this docoment about the pagination paramenters

https://shopify.dev/docs/api/usage/pagination-rest#parameters

for example :

`https://{shop}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2019-07/products.json?page_info=hijgklmn&limit=3`